# How Long Till My Funds Show Up In My Mist Wallet?

Tags: go-ethereum, ether, mist, myetherwallet

Total noob question, but I recently bought some ETH on the Kraken exchange and I also downloaded the mist wallet, made a password and added a new account. After withdrawing the ETH from the exchange to my wallet, I was just wondering how long until it actually shows up in the wallet? And I'm not sure if there's anything additionally I have to do besides what was mentioned above. I hear stuff about syncing the wallet and I'm not sure how to go about doing that exactly. Not very tech savy and new to the crypto world in general. Any help would be appreciated. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Your Mist must be fully synced to the block where the transaction was sent before your balances will show. Depending on your computer and internet connection, that could be in an hour or a day.

You can check your balance on etherscan.io or ethplorer.io in the meantime. Simply paste your address into the search bar and it will pull up your address and transaction history.